# pgfdeclareshape fillable background path with invisible parts

Tags: tikz-pgf, width

I want to make a new shape from rectangle, which has only its top and bottom line drawn, but which can be filled. The answer, thank's to Andrew Stacy and percusse look by now as follows:

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \documentclass[twoside,reqno,12pt]{amsart}
    \usepackage{a4wide} %% uncomment if a4wide is not installed
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% T i k Z 
    %%   -- packages
    %%   -- macros & shapes
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%
    %% new shape : iso
    %%
    \makeatletter
    \newif\ifpullback
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/pullback/.is if=pullback}
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/pullback=false}
    \pgfdeclareshape{iso}{%
        %
        \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
        \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
        %
        \savedanchor\centerpoint
        {
            \pgf@x=0pt
            \pgf@y=0pt
        }
        \anchor{text}{%
             \pgf@x=0pt
             % adjust vertical positioning
             \pgf@y=0pt
             \advance\pgf@y by -0.2\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
        }
        %
        \backgroundpath{%
          \northeast \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
          \southwest \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
          \begingroup
             \tikz@mode
             \iftikz@mode@draw
                % -- draw top and bottom line
                \pgfpathmoveto\northeast
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
                \pgfpathmoveto\southwest
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
                \pgfusepath{stroke}
             \fi
             \iftikz@mode@fill
                % -- fill rectangle if demanded
            \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgflinewidth}
                \advance\pgf@ya by -0.5\pgflinewidth%
                \advance\pgf@yb by  0.5\pgflinewidth%
                \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
                \pgfusepath{fill}
             \fi
             \ifpullback
                % -- if option pullback is given draw hook
            \northeast \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
                \southwest \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
                \pgf@xc=\pgf@xb
                \advance\pgf@xc by  3\pgflinewidth
                \pgf@yc=\pgf@ya
                \advance\pgf@yc by -2\pgflinewidth
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@ya}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
                \pgfusepath{stroke}
             \fi
        \endgroup
        }
    }
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,-2) grid (6,3);
      \node[fill=blue!20,line width=2pt,iso,draw,minimum width=2.5cm,inner ysep=0pt] at (2,2){$=$};
      \node[fill=green!20,pullback,line width=1.25pt,iso,draw,minimum width=2.5cm,inner ysep=0pt] at (2,1){$=$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This solution also takes care of the fact that the rectangle used to fill the
box overrides part of the top and bottom lines, halving their width. Hence
before drawing the filler rectangle, the northeast and southwest y-coordinates are altered by half \pgflinewidth. On option `pullback` is added which draws a small hock in the top left corner. [This shape is meant to depict a iso-2-cell in 2-tangles for 2-categories].

Comment: Short answer is that you can't.  A path has to have constant width and so you can't have some bits invisible and some visible.  So you need two paths, as percusse's answer gives. (Longer explanation at the question I linked to under percusse's answer)

Comment: It's best to leave the question as the question, otherwise it's hard for others to see what the problem was and so to benefit from the answer. If you feel that the code you actually end up with is interestingly different to the answer you were given the it is quite alright to post your own answer - just make sure to attribute it correctly, and ettiquete says you shouldn't accept your own answer if it was derived from another's.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I agree with both of you and glad that a simple swap was adequate. Indeed you can show off your end solution with an image that you can upload to your answer (via using the image button on the toolbar).

Answer (score 3):

The following does the job (thanks to Andrew Stacey's nice correction).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{iso}{%
%
\inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
\inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
%
\savedanchor\centerpoint
{
    \pgf@x=0pt
    \pgf@y=0pt
}
\anchor{text}{%
  \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
  \advance\pgf@y by -0.2pt
}
%
\backgroundpath{%
\northeast \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
\southwest \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
\begingroup
\tikz@mode

\iftikz@mode@fill
\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\northeast}{\southwest}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\fi
\iftikz@mode@draw

\pgfpathmoveto\northeast
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathmoveto\southwest
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
    \fi
    \endgroup
}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[iso,draw,fill=yellow] (a) at (0,0) {slight yellow};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to test `\iftikz@mode@fill`.  See this question for an example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45567/86

Comment: @AndrewStacey I took a slightly different path but I am not sure if it is indeed robust.

Comment: You're restricting your options that way.  You can't use `color` and you can't turn off the drawn lines.  Okay, so it's hard to imagine wanting to do those with this example, but it's good discipline to not impose unnecessary restrictions.

Comment: @AndrewStacey That's indeed my motivation since if you don't need the lines you don't use the `iso` key anyway.

Comment: True.  But you could do an `every node/.style={iso}` if you only had a few that didn't need the lines, then not draw those lines on the few rather than changing the shapes.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Aha, touché!

Comment: I'm just nitpicking here, you know.

Comment: Dear both, great help! I still have the problem that the filling mixes the line width up. I tried to change the order of the code, first filling, then drawing the lines, but I have possibly to do the math with the linewidth (shrink y-axis of the filled rectangle by half linewidth top and bottom).

Comment: @BertfriedFauser Glad that it helps. Can you elaborate on the possible mixup? It's best if you can edit your question and put an image showing the exact problem with the code snippet leading to it (which you have already but without line width ). It's also great if your code is able to be copy/pasted and compiled directly since we can see if any other packages are interfering or not.

Comment: @percusse I have edited my question and put there my current code, which does at the moment what I want. The problem with the lines is, that using \northeast \southwest as coordinates of the filler rectangle, it overlaps with the top and bottom lines halving their width. As I code math objects by different width, I want
to be able to control that width. The present code does just that. It adds also a feature to draw a small hook if the iso is a pullback. I don't know how to add a picture showing the output, but the above code compiles.

Comment: Ah, I didn't spot that.  You should *always* fill before you draw.

Comment: (I've taken the liberty of swapping the order in the code, that should work now)

Comment: @AndrewStacy Sorry for editing the question, it occurred to me odd to `answer' my own question, I just wanted to have the working code here [anyhow your and percusses solution]. Will remember the next time. The flipping to first fill then draw did not get the right linewidth for me [perhaps I did it wrongly], that's why I shrank the filler rectangle.